# Форматы вывода чисел в FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

Как в FORTRAN задать определенное число значащих цифр? То есть допустим у меня есть числа 1.14222, 23.425 и 423.4242, но нужно вывести только 4 значащих цифры, то есть 1.142, 23.42, 423.4. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Прочитайте о квалификаторе формата 'G', он об этом, но, возможно, вам хочется немного иного.

```
print '(3g12.4)', 1.14222, 23.425, 423.4242
```

Выдаст:

```
     1.142       23.42       423.4
```